# How to delete a file with a "Symbol for NULL" character (0x2400) in filename

Tags: bash, macos, shell, null, rm

**ATTN: shell gods ;)**

I can't seem to figure out how to delete a file with a unicode character 0x2400 in the filename on OSX (Example: ␀.test).

It's not a NULL character per-se, but a "symbol for null". (See: http://unicodelookup.com/#null/1)

**Script - How to Reproduce**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

dir="${HOME}/test_dir"

# Create Directory: ~/test_dir
if [ ! -d "${dir}" ]; then
  printf "\nCreating Directory: ${dir}\n"
  mkdir ${dir}
fi

# Create our character
char=$'\xE2\x90\x80'

# Create filename
file="${dir}/${char}.test"

# Create the File
printf "\nCreating File: ${file}\n"
touch ${file}
```

**Delete the file... NOPE!**

```
# Attempt 1 - Delete File
printf "\nDeleting File: ${file}\n"
rm -rf ${file}
```

**Delete the whole directory... NOPE!**

```
# Attempt 2 - Delete Directory
printf "\nDeleting Directory: ${file}\n"
rm -rf ${dir}
```

**Delete the file via inode... NOPE!**

```
# Attempt 3 - Delete File
inode=$(ls -i1 ${dir} | awk '{print $1}')
printf "\nDeleting via Inode: ${inode}\n"
find ${dir} -inum ${inode} -exec rm -i {} \;
```

**The whole script should output something like this:**

```
Creating File: /Users/bsmith/test_dir/␀.test

Deleting File: /Users/bsmith/test_dir/␀.test
rm: /Users/bsmith/test_dir/␀.test: Invalid argument

Deleting Directory: /Users/bsmith/test_dir/␀.test
rm: /Users/bsmith/test_dir/␀.test: Invalid argument
rm: /Users/bsmith/test_dir: Directory not empty

Deleting via Inode: 68592933
remove /Users/bsmith/test_dir/␀.test? y
rm: /Users/bsmith/test_dir/␀.test: Invalid argument
```

Comment: If there are no other files with this suffix: `rm ?.test`

Comment: Doesn't work:

rm: ␀.test: Invalid argument

Comment: `rm -i *` and then just say yes to the one you care about? Though I would guess that's the same as @Cyrus suggestion.  Anyway, off topic. Take it to superuser or the apple site, I guess.

Comment: @CarlNorum - Same issue, this is basically my "attempt #3" above.

    `rm -i *` yields `remove ␀.test? y` `rm: ␀.test: Invalid argument`

Comment: Looks like it is a OSX 10.11 issue only (at least it does not affect older versions) http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/225880/205878

Comment: Word is, upgrading to the (currently) new macOS Sierra resolves this, a quick test is ```cd /tmp; touch ␀.txt; rm ␀.txt```. If that errors out, then you'll never be able to delete that file.

Comment: @Cody-PHP-jQuery - maybe you can use the Finder.

Answer (score 0):

This command works for me:

```
rm ?.test
```

But sadly it is very probable that it will NOT work for you.

It is a known bug of osx:

[Is it impossible to delete/move a file named “␀” on mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/224505)

[Rename folder with odd characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/253932/190466)

The sure bet is to boot from a pen drive with some Linux OS, mount the file system in such Linux, and erase the file. It is sure that files with such names could be erased in Linux.